# How to set up multiple taxonomies for groups of posts

Tags: posts, categories, custom-taxonomy

I have a site that has several types of posts, with categories for each: a News section (categories: Local, International, Breaking), a Video section (categories: Music, Kids, Holidays), and a Photo section (categories: Wedding, Portrait, Landscape).

Unfortunately out-of-the-box, Wordpress is set up for a group of posts. But I need a way to present the various sections/categories in the admin (and set up in my code) in a simple clear way.

I think I should set up custom post types for each of the main types of posts (News, Video, Photo) and then custom taxonomies assigned to each of those... is that right? Just want to find the most flexible, correct way to accomplish what I'm trying to do. The user should always be able to edit the categories for each type of post, and ideally I'd like the flexibility for the user to add new types of posts if possible.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking to create custom taxonomies you can take a look on [WCK](http://wordpress.org/plugins/wck-custom-fields-and-custom-post-types-creator/) plugin, where the  Taxonomy Creator allows you to easily create and edit custom taxonomies for WordPress without any programming knowledge. It provides an UI for most of the arguments of register_taxonomy() function.